# Hide and show a div based on search input with multiple tags

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to search with multiple tags.

But for some reason, it isn't working, it shows just the h5 tags as results.

How would you change the code that it works?

Is it because of the NodeList? For a single tag it is working with `Document.getElementsByTagName()`

Can i convert a NodeList to a HTMLCollection?

```
const searchBar = document.forms['search-webinare'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  const webinare = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('h3,h5'), 0);
  var hasResults = false;
  webinare.forEach(function(webinar) {
    const title = webinar.textContent;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
      webinar.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
      hasResults = true;
    } else {
      webinar.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```
<form id="search-webinare">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen Sie ein Webinar ... "/>
</form>
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text1</h3>
      <h5>text2</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text3</h3>
      <h5>text4</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text5</h3>
      <h5>text6</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: h5 are the tags, correct? And you want to search them or the title. If something matches you want to display booth (h5 + h3), correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` on a NodeList. ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)) An array is not needed.

[Lars Flieger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67252326/4726998#answer-67252985) has a good explanation on why your code is not doing what your want but I think it's easier to loop through parent divs and then search for your term in children elements. (Note that finding parents of an element is also possible with the [element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function)

`querySelector` functions are also available on elements ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector))

So I propose to loop through parent divs and then try to find headings in each div which match your term.
If your term is not found anywhere then your can directly show or hide your parent div element.
Note that I added a class to parent divs to select them but other selectors can be used depending on there positions in the document.

```js
const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-webinare input');

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  const parentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
  parentDivs.forEach(function(parentDiv) {
    const headings = parentDiv.querySelectorAll('h3, h5');
    let match = false;
    headings.forEach(function(heading) {
        const title = heading.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (title.indexOf(term) > -1) {
            match = true
        }
    });
    if (match) {
      parentDiv.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
      parentDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* just for easier visualisation of parents */
.parent {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<form id="search-webinare">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen Sie ein Webinar ... "/>
</form>
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text1</h3>
      <h5>text2a</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text2b</h3>
      <h5>text3a</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <h3>text3b</h3>
      <h5>text4</h5>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you are able to modify the parent div of h3/h5:

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-webinare'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
  const webinare = document.querySelectorAll('div.content')
  let hasResults = false;

  webinare.forEach(webinar => {
    const titleOfh3 = webinar.querySelector('h3').textContent;
    const titleOfh5 = webinar.querySelector('h5').textContent;

    if (titleOfh3.toLowerCase().includes(term) || titleOfh5.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
      webinar.style.display = 'block';
      hasResults = true;
    } else {
      webinar.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="search-webinare">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen Sie ein Webinar ... " />
</form>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="content">
            <h3>text1</h3>
            <h5>text2</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="content">
            <h3>text3</h3>
            <h5>text4</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="content">
            <h3>text5</h3>
            <h5>text6</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or this if not:

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-webinare'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
  const webinare = document.querySelectorAll('h3, h5')
  let hasResults = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < webinare.length; i += 2) {
    const titleOfh3 = webinare[i].textContent;
    const titleOfh5 = webinare[i + 1].textContent;

    if (titleOfh3.toLowerCase().includes(term) || titleOfh5.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
      webinare[i].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
      webinare[i + 1].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
      hasResults = true;
    } else {
      webinare[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      webinare[i + 1].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="search-webinare">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen Sie ein Webinar ... " />
</form>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>text1</h3>
            <h5>text2</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>text3</h3>
            <h5>text4</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>text5</h3>
            <h5>text6</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### What is the problem with your solution?

The problem with your code is **the order** you check if the term is matching: If you try to search for a h5:

[image]

The parent element gets displayed since the **last operation** of it was to set the `display to block`.

If a search result matches the first, the **second** will **override** the result with `display none`:

[image]

You can solve this issue by: **Adding a class to the parent div** (no there is no parent selector based on childs yet) and select this one and change the search logic to check the h3 and h5 in one step. (This is the simplest one and if you are able to add stuff to the parent div: I recommend you this.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, but i have to ask regarding the class for the parent div. When i add a class to the first div, how would i edit the code to display?

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'll update it for you and add it to the answer.